# How to access element inside ng-template? ( Angular 5 )

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng-bootstrap, angular-template

I use the [ngBootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview) library to create a date picker in my program. The html file looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popDate" popoverTitle="Date" placement="bottom">
    {{ my_date_string }}
</button>

<ng-template #popDate>
    <ngb-datepicker #popDatePicker [(ngModel)]="my_date_struct"></ngb-datepicker>
</ng-template>
```

It works, but I would like to navigate to the current month when the user clicks the button and opens the dialog. For that I need to call `.navigateTo()` on the `ngb-datepicker` element.

Unfortunately `@ViewChild('popDatePicker')` is undefined on `ngOnInit`, so I tried it in the onclick method of the button:

```
 (click)="popDatePicker.navigateTo()"
```

But I get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'navigateTo' of undefined
```

How is it possible to solve this error? I have to somehow call a function, when the template is instantiated, but I have no idea how.

---

**Edit**

I can find the element from a `setTimeout` call in `click` event handler, but that does not seem an elegant way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that popover is not yet rendered when you click the button. Try following:

In markup:

```
(click)="btnClick()"
```

In component:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

btnClick(): void {
   setTimeout(() => { 
     this.popDatePicker.navigateTo();
     this.cd.markForCheck();
   });
}
```

Comment: It works, but this `setTimeout` method does not look really elegant

Comment: I just read popover docs and I see (shown) event there. I assume it will fire **after** component is rendered, so you should be ok.

Comment: Look at this example https://plnkr.co/edit/Oe8E8FMUneATd5GXruDB?p=preview